# Inline editing TD with CKEditor in IE10

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, inline-editing

I can make a TD inline editable with CKEditor by using this:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.td = 1
CKEDITOR.inline('td_id');
```

It works in FireFox and Chrome. In IE10 the toolbar appears when I click the TD, but the text cursor doesn't. So it's not possible to edit.

I know TD is not supported by CKEditor. Any hacks anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for a hack... how about wrapping the content to be edited, then unwrapping during save? Something like this untested jQuery dependant code:

```
var td = $('#td_id');
td.html('<div id="blargh">' + td.html() + '</div>');
CKEDITOR.inline('blargh');

// Do your magic and then when prior to saving do something like this
var blarg = $('#blargh');
blarg.parent().html(blarg.html());
```

Comment: If this fails I'll delete the answer.

Comment: This is more or less what I ended up doing myself and it worked. A tip is to add a click handler to the TD that focuses the DIV with $("div").focus(); so clicks outside the DIV doesn't just "disappear".